# can not install, No targets specified and no makefile found. Error

Tags: compiling, make

I'm trying to install [*kiwix*](http://www.kiwix.org/wiki/Main_Page) on `fedora` 23 
when I tried to compile kiwix *[sourcecode](http://download.kiwix.org/src/kiwix-src.tar.xz)* under my computer. and when I want to run `make`, it shows me this message!

```
[ar.lnx@host kiwix-0.9] $ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

## Log

> NOTE: I follow the installation steps *[here](http://www.kiwix.org/wiki/Compilation)*

```
[ar.lnx@host kiwix-0.9] $ ./autogen.sh
configure.ac:45: installing './compile'
configure.ac:38: installing './missing'
src/components/contentManager/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
[ar.lnx@host kiwix-0.9] $ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking for upx... 0
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for Xcode... no
checking for zip... zip
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking for perl... perl
checking for java... java
checking for javah... javah
checking for jarsigner... jarsigner
checking for stat64... yes
Package libxul was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libxul.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxul' found
configure: WARNING: unable to determine Gecko SDK version
checking for Gecko version... 0
configure: WARNING: unable to find nsISupports.idl
checking for xpidl... no
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: WARNING: unable to find either the xpidl binary or the typelib.py or header.py scripts in '/home/ar.lnx/Documents/kiwix-0.9/src/dependencies/xulrunner-sdk/bin' directory.
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... yes
checking for xapian-config... no
configure: error: cannot find xapian-config
[ar.lnx@host kiwix-0.9] $ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[ar.lnx@host kiwix-0.9] $
```

could anybody help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is right in the output. It says:

```
configure: error: cannot find xapian-config
```

So, you'll need that — and it looks like we have it packaged in Fedora... do

```
sudo dnf install /usr/bin/xapian-config
```

Then, rerun `./configure`. You may have further problems; continue to resolve them in the same way (check for error messages saying something is missing, then add that thing) until it runs without error.

Comment: i did not take a detailed look on the log! that helps, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's general good advice to do that. :)

Comment: Sometimes, an error is buried, but in this case it's right at the end. A good approach when faced with something like this is to start at the bottom and scan up for anything that looks like an error.